# Fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fsns'" in google colab for Attention ocr

Tags: python, tensorflow, ocr, attention-model

I am trying to run the aocr in google colab for ocr detection but I seem to get the above error. I am trying the attention_ocr from the tensorflow github documentation.

I tried changing path using export. I have tried with both python 2 and 3. Also I did change the `import fsns` to `from . import fsns` also `from datasets import fsns` told in the github issues

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 30, in <module>
    import common_flags
  File "/content/models/research/attention_ocr/python/common_flags.py", line 22, in <module>
    import datasets
  File "/content/models/research/attention_ocr/python/datasets/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import fsns
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fsns'
```

How to solve this so that I can use this program?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup PYTHONPATH to current dataset directory. Like on Windows.

```
#from python/datasets

set PYTHONAPTYH=YOUR_PATH\python\datasets
```